# How to use an Access database on a ftp-server using OleDBConnection?

Tags: c#-4.0

I want my program to grab his information from an Access database which is on my site.
But everytime I try to use the following, it tries to go to a local file on my computer.

```
path = "@/91.200.49.10/School Agenda.mdb"
connstring = "Provider=Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source = " + path;
```

The result of using that piece of code is this:

```
C:\Projects\School Agenda\School Agenda\bin\Debug\@\91.200.49.10\School Agenda.mdb
```

How do I fix this?